# JPA auto-increment is not updated if data with same id is already inserted

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have to classes Category with auto increment

```
@Id //The unique id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="category", orphanRemoval = false)
@Column(nullable = true)
private List<SubCategory> subCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();

public Category(String categoryname) {
    this.name = categoryname;
}
```

And subcategory

```
@Id //The unique id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="category_id")
Category category;

/**
 * @param name
 */
public SubCategory(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}
```

I have also a file data.sql in my classpath. This file is loaded when I start my spring boot application in order to insert default values

```
--insert default category
INSERT INTO public.category(id, name)   VALUES (1, 'Webtoon');
INSERT INTO public.category(id, name)   VALUES (2, 'Ebook');
INSERT INTO public.category(id, name)   VALUES (3, 'Education');

--insert sub category
INSERT INTO public.sub_category(id, name, category_id)  VALUES (1, 'Action', 1);
INSERT INTO public.sub_category(id, name, category_id)  VALUES (2, 'Adventure', 1);
INSERT INTO public.sub_category(id, name, category_id)  VALUES (3, 'Thriller', 1);
```

Once the application is started when I call my service to create another subcategory I got an Id publication exception

```
    Optional<Category> categoryOpt =  categoryService.findById(Long.parseLong("1"));
    Assert.assertTrue("The category mus be present",categoryOpt.isPresent()); //The data with id 1 is found
    Assert.assertNotNull("The category must not be null. It should be loaded from ressources", categoryOpt.get().getId());

    //Spring generate id  instead of getting the correct sequence in database
    Category category = new Category("My-Category-Test");
    category = categoryService.create(category);

    Assert.assertNotNull("Category id must not be null", category.getId());
```

Instead of getting the correct sequence from data base Spring generate it's own sequence, with already existed data. so I got this exception :

> 2020-01-29 01:00:02.848 TRACE 9148 --- [nio-9103-exec-1]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
>   [BIGINT] - [1] 2020-01-29 01:00:02.849 TRACE 9148 ---
>   [nio-9103-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding
>   parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [My-Category-Test] 2020-01-29
>   01:00:02.860  WARN 9148 --- [nio-9103-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
>   23505 2020-01-29 01:00:02.860 ERROR 9148 --- [nio-9103-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERREUR: the value of a
>   duplicate key breaks the unique constraint « sub_category_pkey »

How could I tell to JPA to found the correct sequence ?

Comment: Can you share database structure and their relationship? If you setup auto increment then it doesn't make sense to pass id manually.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel you are right, it is the fact to pass the id manually that causes the error

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When the id is hard coded added, the auto-increment is not used, that's why hibernate still point to 1 for example even if 1 is already inserted manually.

So I change my script to use auto increment like this

```
--insert default category
INSERT INTO public.category(name)   VALUES ('Webtoon');
INSERT INTO public.category(name)   VALUES ('Ebook');
INSERT INTO public.category(name)   VALUES ('Education');

--insert sub category
INSERT INTO public.sub_category(name, category_id) SELECT 'Action', id FROM public.category where public.category.name = 'Webtoon';
INSERT INTO public.sub_category(name, category_id) SELECT 'Adventure', id FROM public.category where public.category.name = 'Webtoon';
INSERT INTO public.sub_category(name, category_id) SELECT 'Thriller', id FROM public.category where public.category.name = 'Webtoon';
```

With this, the auto-increment is used by the database and by hibernate